# how to create an array with subobjects of another array in angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

Hi guys i am really stuck here,

i am creating a basic comment rating system which has subcomment feature

[image]

as you see in comments array > "subcomments" entries are objects and i want create array with them but i dont know how because theyre in an array.

i tried this:

```
    this.CommentsArray.forEach((item, i) => {


  if([item]["subcomments"] != undefined) {

     [item]["subcomments"].forEach((subitem, i) => {

        subitem = this.subCommentsArray[i];
    }) 



  }
```

but its not working. any suggestions ?

thanks..

edit:

my data structure is like that:

```
"comments" : {
        "d4894e47181e43b7a0fb8b7699" : {
          "commentDate" : "2018-08-13T19:49:49.814Z",
          "commentPhotoExistence" : false,
          "commentRate" : "3",
          "commentRateState" : false,
          "commentTagState" : false,
          "commentText" : "",
          "commentUID" : "d4894e47181e43b7a0fb8b7699",
          "commenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
          "commenterUsername" : "Test2",
          "subcomments" : {
            "7c9f985d39334573b0211d18f1" : {
              "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:57:10.523Z",
              "subcommentText" : "EXAMPLE TEXT1",
              "subcommentUID" : "7c9f985d39334573b0211d18f1",
              "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
              "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2"
            },
            "a1197fb32eae483ba8e910a748" : {
              "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:29:57.514Z",
              "subcommentText" : "EXAMPLE TEST 2",
              "subcommentUID" : "a1197fb32eae483ba8e910a748",
              "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
              "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2"
            },
            "ad648a09a67c431c821bf8f290" : {
              "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:57:01.452Z",
              "subcommentText" : "example3",
              "subcommentUID" : "ad648a09a67c431c821bf8f290",
              "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
              "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2"
            },
            "f7682639d4584642a18a9a4ad7" : {
              "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-02T15:41:38.162Z",
              "subcommentText" : "example4",
              "subcommentUID" : "f7682639d4584642a18a9a4ad7",
              "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
              "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2"
            }
          }
        }
```

the problem here is the subcomment id's are randomly added. in normally if it was Array i can use .forEach for use every item but there are random uid's between subcomments and subcomment properties. So all i want is create an array like including them, array will be like;

```
0: {                   "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:57:01.452Z",
                  "subcommentText" : "example3",
                  "subcommentUID" : "ad648a09a67c431c821bf8f290",
                  "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
                  "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2" 
}
1: {
                  "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:57:01.452Z",
                  "subcommentText" : "example3",
                  "subcommentUID" : "ad648a09a67c431c821bf8f290",
                  "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
                  "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2" 
}

2: {
                  "subcommentDate" : "2018-09-01T11:57:01.452Z",
                  "subcommentText" : "example3",
                  "subcommentUID" : "ad648a09a67c431c821bf8f290",
                  "subcommenterUID" : "17QYQbhmyQeIYocIZBwH8R7ojhg1",
                  "subcommenterUsername" : "Test2" 
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is shadowing the variable `i`.

You're using is on your first line `this.CommentsArray.forEach((item, i) => {` then again on the `subcomments`.

```js
this.CommentsArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  if([item]["subcomments"] != undefined) {
    [item]["subcomments"].forEach((subitem, z) => {
      subitem = this.subCommentsArray[z];
    }) 
  }
});
```

But that's not the real problem. You're trying to iterate an object, not an array. The result will be coming back as;

```
{
  "d48...669": {
    "commentDate": '2019-08-13',
    "subcomments": {
      "7c9...8f1": {

      },
      "a11...748": {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should iterate by the keys of the object;

```js
Object.keys(this.CommentsArray).forEach(commentId => {
  const comment = this.CommentsArray[commentId];

  Object.keys(comment['subcomments']).forEach(subCommentId => {
    const subComment = comment['subcomments'][subCommentId];
  )};
});
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. But i am getting an error like: ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Basicly, i just want a create subcomments array just like my comments array, for rest html will do the job.

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but the overall structure should work, if you use a method like this you should be able to extract your subcomments array.

Comment: but the problem is .forEach is just for Arrays.. I dont have array i actually want to create array. object.keys is not working because i have a "randomuid" between subcomment and subcomment properties. I edited the question thanks for your help

Comment: You're doing it the right way by having random ID's instead of arrays in Firebase. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: But im taking the commentsArray data which already includes subcommentsArray once, So taking subcomments data seperately would go hard on traffic, so all i need is create the subcommentsArray by running some codes on my commentsArray. Thats angular, and i dont know how.